# The contact form does not work

Tags: php, html, forms

I purchased a template, but there was no mailer file included, I'm trying to get this working. This is the form:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well">
          <form id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake" action="mailer.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-group"><!-- ENTER MANE -->
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required data-error="NEW ERROR MESSAGE">
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><!-- ENTER EMAIL -->
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><!-- ENTER MESSAGE -->
              <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- button form submit -->
            <div class="submit">
<!--               <button id="form-submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button> -->
              <input id="form-submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" value="Submit">
              <div id="msgSubmit" class="h5 h5 text-danger hidden"></div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

          </form>
```

And here's the old mailer file that I purchased with a different template:

```
<?php
$email_to = "example@domain.com"; // write your email here, or email where it has to be sent
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$text = "NAME: $name<br>
         EMAIL: $email<br>   
         MESSAGE: $message";
mail($email_to, "Subject", $text);
?>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Try to put the mail function in an if-statement and look or it's true.

Comment: are u sending the email to that email address provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like email where it should be sent is wrong. Set correctly `$email_to` variable with email where you want to receive messages.

Also with `mail()` you dont have to set headers. You can simplify it:

```
<?php
$email_to = "example@domain.com"; // write your email here, or email where it has to be sent
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$text = "NAME: $name<br>
         EMAIL: $email<br>   
         MESSAGE: $message";
mail($email_to, "Subject", $text);
?>
```

Also I wouldn't use in your case validator which you don't understand and is taken from another site.

There might be a problem with your button in `HTML` looks like submit should be done by JavaScript. If not you should change

```
<button id="form-submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<input id="form-submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**Debug**

if you are getting an empty message try:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

to check what is inside `$_POST` array.

---

**Manual**

[PHP: mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: The submit button doesn't seem to be working at all. Nothing happens when I press it. Maybe there is an issue with the HTML and not PHP?

Comment: Add in submit button: `type="submit"`. So it will be: `<button id="form-submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>`. It looks like before someone used a javascript to submit form.

Comment: Or even make it like this: `<input id="form-submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: I did, still nothing when I press the button...

Comment: You added `<input ...` ?

Comment: Yeah, I changed 'button' to 'input' and it doesn't work. What else do you suggest?

Comment: You need there also `type="submit"`. The best way is just copy that `<input ... ` which I wrote for you. There I didn't change only button to input, there is more differences.

Comment: I did copy the entire input element you included in your answer..

Comment: Edit your question and paste current code please.

Comment: I've pasted the current code.

Comment: Remove `data-toggle="validator"` in `<form ....` in `HTML` because your validator may not allow form to be sent.

Comment: And if still not working, delete there `id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake"`. I have no idea how your validator works and it may cause a problems.

Comment: The form works now, but upon submitting I'm redirected to mailer.php and it says "access denied"

Comment: Ok, it works now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)